# My wordpress local urls is still displayed even moved to live

Tags: plugins, customization, theme-development, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

My wordpress local urls is still displayed in some pages even moved to live. How do i fix this,

local urls displayed in "canonical link", " meta property="og:locale" code, "schema code".

NB: We are using Yoast seo plugin

Comment: How did you change your URLs when you moved it to production?

Comment: We are importing files from local host and export to live host. Most of the Pages are shown live urls, expect  some pages.

Comment: When you say import/export though, how? Do you mean a database dump? Or do you mean the WP importer/exporter plugin? I notice there is no URL search replace in your migration step

Comment: I will share the pages, Colud you please check it https://www.dhyanit.com/company/about-us/
                                                                      
https://www.dhyanit.com/2020/04/15/plan-your-smart-street-journey-with-streetman-platform/

Comment: This isn't something people can help with by just looking at the frontend of the site, you need to do a search replace of your database to change the old URLs to the new URLs

Comment: The issues successfully fixed with the help of Yoast Test Helper.